# How to open a file with my app? (When my app is in the background)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

My app reads some kind of file(*.mndl) and with below method I can open a file if other app requires it (Using the options parameter).

```
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

It works fine, but when my app is still alive in background and other app requires to open a file it won't happen since that method is not called anymore, instead `applicationDidBecomeActive:` and/or `applicationWillEnterForeground:`, etc are called

What options do I have?

I wouldn't like to terminate my app everytime I want to import some file from Mail.app from example. ;(

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you've checked this out, but there's a good section on opening files in the documentation ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html))

There's a section in there talking about using `application:handleOpenURL:` or `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` to open the file, perhaps that's what you're looking for?